# JobConf size exceeded

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map reduce job which uses a very large number of input paths. Consequently I am running into this exception while starting the job:

Exceeded max jobconf size: 6154861 limit: 5242880

I realized that the max jobconf size is governed by the system property:

mapred.user.jobconf.limit which defaults to 5 MB.

Is there a way to circumvent this issue other than increasing this limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so unless you are ready to change the source itself. As per JobTracker's source this is the maximum allowed value, if not specified explicitly by the user.

```
/** the maximum allowed size of the jobconf **/
long MAX_JOBCONF_SIZE = 5*1024*1024L;

/** the config key for max user jobconf size **/
public static final String MAX_USER_JOBCONF_SIZE_KEY = "mapred.user.jobconf.limit";
```

If you have not specified any value through `mapred.user.jobconf.limit` then `5*1024*1024L` will be used :

```
MAX_JOBCONF_SIZE = conf.getLong(MAX_USER_JOBCONF_SIZE_KEY, MAX_JOBCONF_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try using `DistributedCache` if possible.

Instead of loading so many name value pairs into `JobConf`, you can put them in a file and add that file to `DistributedCache`.
It depends on what your application is storing in `JobConf`.